# C# InstaSharper: Unable to upload photo: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: S. Path '', line 0, position 0

Tags: c#, json, parsing, image-uploading, instasharp

I'm using this library as a NuGet package(InstaSharper) for instagram bot program: https://github.com/a-legotin/InstaSharper

And in the `InsertImage();` function, which is meant for uploading a photo to instagram page, while parsing, the program runs into a problem and console reuturns:

> Loged in! Unable to upload photo: Unexpected character encountered
>   while parsing value: S. Path '', line 0, position 0.

I tried using different paths and image types, but the same thing happens.

What could be the problem and how to fix it?

These are main functions:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            user = new UserSessionData();
            user.UserName = username;
            user.Password = password;

            Login();
            Console.Read();
        }

public static async void Login()
        {
            api = InstaApiBuilder.CreateBuilder().SetUser(user).UseLogger(new DebugLogger(LogLevel.Exceptions)).SetRequestDelay(RequestDelay.FromSeconds(1, 3)).Build();

            var loginRequest = await api.LoginAsync();
            if (loginRequest.Succeeded)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Loged in!");
                InsertImage(@"C:\test.jpg", "Testing");
            }
            else Console.WriteLine("Unable to log in: " + loginRequest.Info.Message);
        }

public static async void InsertImage(string _path, string _caption)
        {
            var mediaImage = new InstaImage
            {
                Height = 1080,
                Width = 1080,
                URI = new Uri(Path.GetFullPath(_path), UriKind.Absolute).LocalPath
            };
            var result = await api.UploadPhotoAsync(mediaImage, _caption);
            if (result.Succeeded == true) Console.WriteLine($"Media created: {result.Value.Pk}, {result.Value.Caption}");
            else Console.WriteLine($"Unable to upload photo: {result.Info.Message}");

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems InstaSharper Nuget Package is not updated, I've downloaded it from Github and use it in my project, it worked for me

Hope this helps